# How to get root node attributes on java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I have an xml file like down below. I want to get pharmacies nodes' latitude and longitude attributes.I can get chilnodes attributes but couldnt get root node attributes. I am new on java and xml. I could not find a solution how to do.

```
<pharmacies Acc="4" latitude="36.8673380" longitude="30.6346640" address="Ayujkila">
        <pharmacy name="sadde" owner="" address="dedes" distance="327.000555668" phone="342343" lat="36.8644" long="30.6345" accuracy="8"/>
        <pharmacy name="Sun " owner="" address="degerse" distance="364.450016586" phone="45623" lat="36.8641" long="30.6353" accuracy="8"/>
        <pharmacy name="lara" owner="" address="freacde" distance="927.262190129" phone="564667" lat="36.8731" long="30.6422" accuracy="8"
    <end/>
    </pharmacies>
```

This is my part of code. I get xml file from a url address.

```
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                 DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                 Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    NodeList nodeList =doc.getElementsByTagName("pharmacy");
                 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
                      Node node =nodeList.item(i);
                      Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                      NodeList pharmacyList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("pharmacy");
                      Element pharmacyElement = (Element) pharmacyList.item(0);
              Element pharmacyElement = (Element) pharmacyList.item(0);

              HashMap<String,String>map=new HashMap<String,String>();                   
              map.put("name", pharmacyElement.getAttribute("name"));
              map.put("distance", pharmacyElement.getAttribute("phone"));
              list.add(map);

              latt.add(pharmacyElement.getAttribute("lat"));

                    ....
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `<pharmacies>` element itself can be obtained using

```
Element pharmacies = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

You can get the attributes from that.

Answer (score 6):

`doc.getDocumentElement()` will return the root element and you can call `getAttribute( attrName )` on it like you would on any other element.

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println(doc.getChildNodes().getLength());
    Node item = doc.getChildNodes().item(0);
    System.out.println(item.getNodeName());
    Node lat = item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("latitude");
    String s = lat.getNodeValue();
    System.out.println(s.equals("36.8673380")); // Value of /pharmacies[@latitude]/value()
```

Comment: Yes it is working just like Skaffman's answer. Thank you very much for helping me out!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pharmacies instead of pharmacy if you need to get attributes for root node pharmacies.And use getAttributes method instead.You can see lot of examples at this site.
http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/xml.html#dom

Answer (score 0):

Try Its Work For me, Res is your final String:

```
doc = b.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    Node rootNode=doc.getDocumentElement();

    res = rootNode.getNodeName().toString();
```

Comment: Dear @user3153156, This will only provide rootNode's name, where the requirement here is to get rootNode's attributes named "latitude" & "longitude". :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<pharmacies>` is itself an element & can be obtained using

`Element pharmacies = doc.getDocumentElement();`

Now this `pharmacies` reference variable of **Elements** holds all the attributes under `<pharmacies>` element. We can get desired attributes one by one using attribute name like :

```
pharmacies.getAttribute("latitude");   // Will give 36.8673380
pharmacies.getAttribute("longitude");  // Will give 30.6346640
```